# Why does my comparator not compare?

Tags: operational-amplifier, dc-dc-converter, buck, comparator

I have designed a buck converter and I am baffled with its comparator's functionality. The op-amp comparator does not give a PWM, instead it gives an amplified ramp.

What am I doing wrong?

Attached is my circuit schematic.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note that it's not a free design house, homework-answering service or on-line technical encyclopedia, copied to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as possible on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Explain the situation, show your work and findings so far in considerable detail with a schematic. The schematic tool here is easy to use. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a warm welcome.

Comment: What are those 4-wire 'E' things? You have no ground reference on the big block of stuff on the top right. Drawing tips: always point grounds downwards (towards the ground). Turn off the grid before taking a screengrab. Avoid spacing components too far apart. The screengrab is barely legible because of this.

Comment: They are voltage controlled voltage sources. I am using ltspice and the are specified as e2, there. Thank you for noting my mistakes but it hasn't solved my issue.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Please draw all positive voltage upwards and ground/negateive downwards. Why are you not using a COTS comparator?

Comment: @AzarHadi can you please clean up that schematic?

Comment: @AzarHadi:  Why have you removed the schematic diagram?

Answer (score 1):

While a VCVS is in many ways a model of an ideal opamp (albeit with finite gain), you can't use it as a comparator unless you provide some way to limit the output voltage to stay within the supply rails. Using an opamp as a comparator relies on the fact that the output saturates -- a nonlinear effect. A VCVS is always linear -- it never saturates!

One way to do this is to add a clamping circuit to the output of a VCVS. V+ and V- represent your supply voltages. This requires the addition of a small but nonzero output resistance.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRHDyNm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A better model of a comparator would be a voltage-controlled switch. It has the nonlinear response that you want.

A simple model of a comparator uses just one, but requires a pullup or pulldown resistor. A more ideal version uses two switches.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgdMUc.png)</sup>

Comment: We are asked to use opamp comparators.

Comment: I am using VCVS because the macromodel of the op amp comparator is asked. I cannot use a voltage-controlled switch because I am comparing the output of the amplifier on the right with a ramp, i.e, one of the control inputs to the switch is the same as its regular input!

Comment: I have already explained why your circuit *"does not give a PWM, instead it gives an amplified ramp."* Why are you insisting that it has to be different?

Comment: I am not insisting on my knowledge, rather, I am trying to say the assumptions for an assignment cannot be wrong (I am 100 percent sure) and there must be something that I am missing about the macromodel of the comparator. However, you were a great help and I could reach my desired result using a switch comparator, I hope it will be accepted.